# If modelling an Ethereum blockchain, would you use PoW or PoS?

Tags: consensus, pow

I'm modelling an Ethereum network that will hopefully form part of a PhD, which will be used to identify a blockchain's functionality in certain industrial situations.

I wrote my MSc dissertation on the same subject in 2019–2020 using PoW, primarily because academic data on PoS wasn't widely available, but also because the launch of Ethereum 2.0 had experienced several delays. However, as a PhD will likely take three or more years to complete, and it seems like PoS may almost be ready for release(?), my research needs to be relevant when it's completed. Therefore, I'm thinking I should model PoS, and not PoW.

As academic research is notoriously outdated by 18 months or more, I'm hoping this thread  may highlight opinions on Ethereum's future use of PoW and PoS that are yet to reach academic journals. All views will be greatly appreciated, thank you.